# php does not get input from a html form

Tags: php

Here are my codes:

```
<form action="druhy.php" method="post">
message: <textarea name="msg"></textarea><br>
<input type=submit value="Odeslat">
</form>


<? if ( mail("mine@gmail.com", "from PL", $msg,"From: webmaster@example.com") )
{header("Location: sent.htm");}
else {header("Location: nosent.htm");}
?>
```

what happened with the msg variable?

Comment: you're not pulling anything from the form.

Comment: $msg is not defined, try adding    $msg = isset($_POST['msg']); just before the if, you will need to add more filters and validations to this

Comment: so how to pull something from the form?